# Squashfs error post installation of ubuntu 18.04 L

Tags: error-handling, squashfs

I have windows on my laptop, just now i downloaded Ubuntu 18.04 L version from official site and installed it. But when I clicked restart and removed my flash drive my screen was all filled with a huge list of `squashfs` errors, most of which looked the same. How can I fix this?

Comment: squashfs is used by the installer (squashed or read-only file-system) which makes me wonder if you install is valid (did you use the *check disc for defects* before you installed?  if not I'd do it now & consider re-install) which usually is the result of a bad download (of ISO, did you md5sum or otherwise verify it) or write to install-media (which the *check disc for defects* function validates; this is the important one as it'll detect bad ISO generally anyway).

Comment: Maybe worth reading - https://askubuntu.com/questions/993407/is-verifying-isos-downloaded-from-the-official-website-worthwhile/993409#993409