# Installer Crashes in Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive

Installing Ubuntu 21.04 Crashes while copying file to hard disk. The output message

```
The installer encountered an error copying files to the hard disk:

    [Errno 5] Input/output error
    
    This is often due to a faulty CD/DVD disk or drive, or a faulty hard disk. It may help to  clean the CD/DVD, to burn the CD/DVD at a lower speed, to clean the CD/DVD drive lens (cleaning kits are often available from electronics suppliers), to check whether the hard disk is old and in need of replacement, or to move the system to a cooler environment.
```

I tried  installing in two laptops one with 512 GB SSD and other is 1 TB. Both are same ASUS Vivobook 15. Installation occurs smoothly if installed in VMware. Tried two methods of partioning along with windows and also other with root partition around a 100 GB and bootloader in EFI system partition of Windows boot manager. Burned the iso image with balena and tried 2 usb sticks. I have the log files. Is there a workaround available or should  I file a bug?

Edit-01:

I did verify the downloaded iso [https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993407/is-verifying-isos-downloaded-from-the-official-website-worthwhile) by this tutorial provided by @guiverc but in step 5 when I run

`gpg --keyid-format long --verify SHA256SUMS.gpg SHA256SUMS`

the output is

```
gpg: Signature made Fri 23 Apr 2021 01:04:38 AM IST
gpg:                using RSA key 843938DF228D22F7B3742BC0D94AA3F0EFE21092
gpg: BAD signature from "Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012) <cdimage@ubuntu.com>" [unknown]
```

but in last step when I run

`sha256sum -c SHA256SUMS 2>&1 | grep OK`

the output is

`ubuntu-21.04-desktop-amd64.iso: OK`

I am new to this crypto verify thing! Is my iso corrupted?

Comment: Did you verify your ISO?  https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0  as either you have a faulty ISO, or your write to media was flawed.  The issue is bad media (CD refers to your installation media; be it CD/DVD/HDD/SSD/thumb-drive or anything used)...   FYI:  *I find the write to the installation media to be mostly at faulty; about 5-8% failure rate on writes of ISO in my experience*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is verifying ISOs downloaded from the official website worthwhile?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993407/is-verifying-isos-downloaded-from-the-official-website-worthwhile)   (my upvoted answer is the ISO validation one, but there is also another answer there on media checks and how you confirm my belief; ie. squashfs errors)

Comment: It tells you in the error on why it was unable to install. You could try to reinstall the OS to the USB stick or get a new HDD.

Comment: @guiverc As per the tutorial you provided, I checked, but it showed bad signature when running gpg --keyid-format long --verify SHA256SUMS.gpg SHA256SUMS   (in step 5) but in last step  sha256sum -c SHA256SUMS 2>&1 | grep OK  it outputs as per tutorial. I am new to this crypto verify thing! Is my iso corrupted? Regarding Media Installation it is solid, I installed Fedora, and RHEL. No issues with HDD or Media writer.

Comment: It's hard to read detail in comments so please add to your question (greater formatting options exist in questions/answers.  You said you used in VM; if the VM was identical hardware with identical options run, plus you scanned logs for *squashfs* errors that detail is incomplete (like writer had no errors; if writing to usb-thumb-drives no error is ~always given as no validation hardware exists on thumb-drives; they're consumable/cheap/made-to-cost). Validation is a separate step performed whilst 21.04 runs & visible in logs. I believe your write to media is where it failed.

Comment: @guiverc I edited and added details to my question, In my VM I used BIOS as my firmware but my Laptop uses UEFI! I will try to reinstall with UEFI in VM again.And regarding logs, I dont know where to check errors, There are around 17 log files in /var/log. It will be nice if you provide a way to check and Regarding media( My SSD and HDD) I doubt it to be faulty, since they are  less than a year old and other OS installation went smooth.

Comment: The CD mention implies the error is with your installation media (be it CD/DVD/HDD/SSD/thumb-drive/flash-card/magnetic-tape or whatever you're using - CD is used for historical reasons for any installation media regardless of what device its written to) and includes logical/checksum errors and not physical issues. I provided a link with details on checking; see second post & the command I mention on how I check for *squashfs* errors in that link, or if you need another see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1311183/do-i-need-to-check-the-integrity-of-a-ubuntu-install