# Unable to find a medium containing a live file system

Tags: system-installation

I have tried to install ubuntu on my system for several days now. Every attempt ends with the "unable to find a medium containing a live file system" error.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7uXt.jpg)

To date I have tried:

1. Switching to a diffrent pen drive: did not help. Both of my usb sticks worked fine when installing ubuntu on my two other older pcs.
2. Using a usb c hub: No change
3. Installing Ubuntu on a diffrent pc, then transfering the drive to the target pc: Ubuntu does boot, but the wifi card is not properly recognized and it only sees the drive ubuntu is installed when there is 3 other drives. No fix helped me to resolve
4. Installing a motherboard 9 pin 2.0 header --> usb 2.0 connector and using that to install: The installation process looked a little diffrent (i.e. a monochrome ubuntu logo instead of a colourful one) but no change really
5. Installing a diffrent Ubuntu version (18.04): An additional log entry "Unknown chipset". Otherwise no change

My MB is ASUS PRO WS WRX80E-SAGE SE WIFI

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is verifying ISOs downloaded from the official website worthwhile?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993407/is-verifying-isos-downloaded-from-the-official-website-worthwhile)

Comment: The inability to find the medium containing the ISO means either you failed to validate the ISO and there was an error, OR *more likely in my experience* the write of ISO to your installation media, or the installation media itself was faulty.  Did you verify the write of ISO to media?  (read my non-updated answer for more details; or refer https://askubuntu.com/questions/1311183/do-i-need-to-check-the-integrity-of-a-ubuntu-install)

Comment: FYI: Unless the other PC you mention had identical hardware; that is no validation of the ISO being valid & write to media being correct, as the different hardware may have caused different areas of the medium to be used on the media, UNLESS you scanned the system logs to verify that no issues occurred (not all are shown on screen).  Your description does not rule out media issues as per error message you mention.  Note: how you validate media varies on release; you only mention 18.04 where link(s) were provided, plus if a VM you can experience this issue where you allocate too little RAM too

Comment: Thanks for answering. I've tried several versions, mainly 22.0, and several distros too. I'm not sure if it is reasonable that all of them were corrupted

Comment: Ubuntu releases are *year.month* in format, so 22.0 is invalid. If you used the same tool to write all ISOs then all failing would be expected if you used an improper method. Ubuntu ISOs are built for multiple architectures, and since 20.10 (ie. all releases past 20.04) effort is made so all architectures boot the same for a given release. This can mean the ISO format differs between releases meaning  a tool that can write a 20.04 ISO correctly cannot write 20.10 or later correctly (*unless patched for all releases unless direct clone is used*). You need to consider all facts.

Comment: My mistake it was 22.04. I added a screenshot of the error. I mainly used Rufus. Also I have tried to install from a cd drive that I burned from another pc that ran ubuntu, but got the same error message.