# Ubuntu Desktop install Failure

Tags: nvidia, system-installation, usb-installation

When I try and continue from "Update and other software" it just hangs. Then, if I quit it sends me to a live version of Ubuntu desktop but the screen is tinted green. THEN if I try to install I get the following error:

````
ubuntu-drivers crashed with unboundlocalerror in nvidia_desktop_pre_installation_hook(): local variable 'version' referenced before assignment```

Please help!
````

Comment: As we don't know what release you're talking about, we'd only be guessing. Your question also doesn't rule out user procedure checks/errors; ie. did you verify the ISO after download to ensure it was good (*as per doco*) or did the validation of write of ISO to media succeed (*this varies on your unstated release*). If you skipped those checks, you should check for issues during install but didn't mention doing that...

Comment: I’m using the latest release (22.04.1). I didn’t verify the iso but I downloaded it 4 times and tried each one and experienced the same error. When you say to check for issues during install, what do you mean?

Comment: Downloading it four times may increase the chance of download being successful, but it's not the same as validating the checksum (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0) but if you wrote the ISO using the same method, and your writing tool can only handle ISOs up to 20.04 but not later (*there were changes for 20.10 & later, so updated software is required for them to be valid if the ISO isn't cloned directly*); it maybe the ISO writing software can't handle releases past 20.04 which you're trying to use.

Comment: You'll find some answers on this post (https://askubuntu.com/questions/993407/is-verifying-isos-downloaded-from-the-official-website-worthwhile/993409#993409) and I talk about media checks in this answer (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1311183/do-i-need-to-check-the-integrity-of-a-ubuntu-install).  If your issue is nvidia related; as we know nothing about your hardware/card we can't help there (*you gave no details*) but I'd switch to text terminal and read system messages (`dmesg`, `journalctl` etc), even check the media using another machine (ie. just try & not install; then scan logs)

Comment: Thanks for responding @guiverc. I've confirmed that the SHA256 checksum is valid. Here are my system specs: https://hastebin.com/gupugabagu.txt
I've managed to install it before on this PC, just not again. Does this help?