# Cannot install Ubuntu due to screen tear

Tags: 18.04, system-installation

I have been trying to install Ubuntu 18.04.6 Desktop onto my PC with a USB drive for a while but every time when I select the "Try ubuntu without installing" or "Install Ubuntu" option, I just get this black [Screen Tear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBVqh.jpg) (See attached photo) after booting.

After getting this screen tear the PC stops responding and I have no way of getting out of this except holding down the power button down just to turn the machine off.

I wonder if this is a GPU issue or some BIOS setting I messed up. I have tried the same thing with the same USB on other computers so probably not a USB thing.

Any help would be great! Thanks

P.S: Sorry for the lack of info.
The PC specs:
CPU: R7 5800X
GPU: GTX 1660 Ti
RAM: 16GB
[image]
The machine that did install ubuntu successfully is a laptop.

Comment: Maybe you have done the following you have not said so I will tell you. Did you verify the ISO? https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview Did you folow a guide to do the creation of the Live Media and install? https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview

Comment: You've not been specific as to which Ubuntu 18.04 product you're talking about, nor which kernel stack option you're trying to boot (ie. Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Server? Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop? or 18.04.1? 18.04.2? 18.04.3? etc) as for graphic problems - the kernel stack can make a difference.  Did you verify your ISO prior to write to media? and then the write of your ISO to your installation media?  (I'd suggest using another device to verify that if the screen is unreadable). https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck is useful for verifying write to media on Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop

Comment: Why don't you try a newer version, like 20.04, 22.04, or 22.10? What's the hardware, GPU, CPU, etc.?

Comment: Verification is necessary if the hardware was not identical, as different hardware can cause different kernel modules (aka *drivers*) to be read from the installation media.. Your other machine boot is valid though if you confirmed the verification using that hardware (ie. read the whole of the installation media!). Is your other machine(s) using identical hardware?   Please add (or correct) details in your actual question; this is a Q&A site (not a forum) & comments will be deleted once addressed in your question.

Comment: I will try to verify all the ISO as instructed.

Comment: It's fixed! I created a new bootable USB with a fresh download ISO and it worked. It might have had something to do with the ISO image. Thanks all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do I need to check the integrity of a Ubuntu install?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1311183/do-i-need-to-check-the-integrity-of-a-ubuntu-install)