# Installing ubuntu on a machine that is not listed on Ubuntu certified desktops fails

Tags: system-installation, live-usb, grub-efi

I am trying to install ubuntu 20.04.6-desktop-amd64 in an old pc (Lenovo ThinkCentre m73 tiny 10AX0053JP). I bought here in an auction site. I used rufus and had the partition scheme set to "GPT". I got through Grub menu (Install Ubuntu) -> Loading screen (checking disk loads perfectly but installing process halts because of "Errno 5 Input/output error". I tried every minimal options during installation process like proceeding without internet connection, choosing minimal installation and erase ubuntu and install (because I've been repeting this installation process for 10 times). I already checked for checksum if it matches the one on ubuntu website using rufus and found no problem.

Error that I have got:

[image: SCreen image]

PC specs:

- CPU: 2.4GHz   2cores
- RAM: 8gb DDR3/DDR3L PC3-12800
- Intel HD Graphics
- HDD:  7200 rpm
- HDDinterface: SATA

Comment: Have a look here https://askubuntu.com/questions/65830/errno-5-input-output-error-when-trying-to-install-ubuntu   It seems likely to be a hardware error on this pretty old computer, as you’ve checked your iso. I’d try running in live session (which will test your ram / mobo), and run some disk checks from the live session. It may be you need a new ssd - that would be my prediction.

Comment: Have you thought about looking at how it's mentioning a failed drive? I have hit this issue a few times on old hardware when the drive was on its last legs.

Comment: Does that mean this pc is too old? I checked it was released in January 2014, I goes that is pretty old by today standards but I was in the impression that it can handle ubuntu... Are there other choice I have?

Comment: I am sorry can you give more info on how can I check about the failing drive?

Comment: @joyfuljoy So in the error you can see it mention that it could be a failing disk, you should be able to do the following:

Open Disks from the Activities overview.

Select the disk you want to check from the list of storage devices on the left. Information and status of the disk will be shown.

Click the menu button and select SMART Data & Self-Tests…. The Overall Assessment should say “Disk is OK”.

See more information under SMART Attributes, or click the Start Self-test button to run a self-test.

Comment: I am sorry I m very noob when it comes to linux. When I look at activities overview nothing was there. And as I have ran the installation process again I noticed that it doesn't mention that my ssd is faulty but mentions that my installation media is dirty? (I don't know what does that mean)

Comment: Your machine is not too old, though it will certainly feel sluggish at times. The `Errno 5` is something that I've run into when the ISO I downloaded was incomplete. [Follow this tutorial to verify your ISO](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview). If it checks out, then you *may* have an issue with the USB stick you're using or hard drive you're installing to.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["errno 5 - input/output error" when trying to install Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65830/errno-5-input-output-error-when-trying-to-install-ubuntu)

Comment: Check your details.  Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS is the latest 22.04 ISO,  there is no .6 scheduled, and [22.04.5 isn't scheduled until mid-late 2024](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-release-schedule/23906), so unless you've got access to a *time machine* your details are incorrect...  I also suggest you scan https://askubuntu.com/questions/993407/is-verifying-isos-downloaded-from-the-official-website-worthwhile as your issue is either faulty ISO download OR more likely (*in my experience*) invalid write of ISO to media.

Comment: The link provided above is very similar to my problem regarding errno 5 and  SQUASHFS error: zlib decompression failed, data probably corrupt. But it doesn't have any solutions provided.

Comment: @guiverc I am sorry for the typo. You are right I was using Ubuntu 20.04.6-desktop-amd64 not 22.04.6

Comment: @guiverc When I used rufus 4.0 I did follow the instructions such as checking the checksum if it matches the one on ubuntu site, using partition scheme GPT ( btw I also tried MBR still no luck), using File system fat32 (default). Other than that I couldn't find any more specific options. Am I missing something?

Comment: Much of the ISO you install is stored as a *squashfs* or squashed/compressed file-system... ie. the *squashfs* errors are inability to read your installation media thus it cannot read the data in order to install it to your destination.  Causes are (1) your ISO download was invalid.. anything done after that is lost, (2) invalid write of ISO to media (most common in my experience writing >100 per year to thumb-drive) or (3) you have a faulty thumb-drive (they're cheap media made to cost; I throw out 5+ per year.   Most likely option is 2 in my experience.

Comment: How would I go on about checking if write of ISO to media is invalid? If (2) doesn't fix the problem I might buy a new thumb-drive.

Comment: FYI:  The `rufus` issue I mentioned applied only to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS ISOs you originally said you used... thus I deleted that comment when you clarified it was a 20.04 ISO.  Rufus has no issues writing 20.04 ISOs to my knowledge (I'm 99.99% sure on that too).  (Rufus has/had an issue when ISOs get beyond a size, Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop ISOs were larger than NTFS as used by `rufus` can/could handle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much of the ISO you install is stored as a *squashfs* or squashed/compressed file-system... ie. the *squashfs* errors are inability to read your installation media thus it cannot read the data in order to install it to your destination.

Causes are

- your ISO download was invalid.. anything done after that is lost,
- invalid write of ISO to media (*most common in my experience writing >100 ISOs per year to thumb-drive*) or
- you have a faulty thumb-drive (*they're cheap media made to cost; I throw out 5+ per year*).

Most likely option is 2 (*invalid write*) in my experience.

Some brand/models have *firmware* that has issues that are *unique*...  (*Sorry I don't know your hardware*) but *squashfs* errors scream media errors as already explained.

FYI:  I use hardware as old as 2005 for *Quality Assurance* (QA) testing of Ubuntu and *flavors* of Ubuntu.

As for checking if the write of ISO is valid etc.. refer to the link I posted before, ie. an answer I wrote on [Is verifying ISOs downloaded from the official website worthwhile?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993407/is-verifying-isos-downloaded-from-the-official-website-worthwhile) or the original answer I wrote on [Do I need to check the integrity of a Ubuntu install?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1311183/do-i-need-to-check-the-integrity-of-a-ubuntu-install).  If I have issues with media I cannot explain, I boot the thumb-drive on two other boxes (*one almost identical, one very different*) and check the media on those boxes.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145950/discussion-on-answer-by-guiverc-installing-ubuntu-on-a-machine-that-is-not-liste); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.