# Validating an ISO write directly after writing

Tags: iso

**Background**

My normal process for writing ISOs is downloading them (`zsync` via script which performs a ISO validation & shows me the package changes (ie. *manifest diff* from prior download)), then use `mkusb` to write it to thumb-drive, eg.

```
guiverc@d7050-next:/de2900/lubuntu_64$ sudo mkusb-nox mantic-desktop-amd64.iso all
```

I then quickly scan messages & if it looks good,  *eject* the thumb-drive, and boot it on a nearby box & confirm media write there using a method documented [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1311183/do-i-need-to-check-the-integrity-of-a-ubuntu-install), ie.

- boot it in *try* mode, and wait awhile to let background media validation occur, scanning the systemd journal using

`sudo journalctl |grep casper-md5check`

watching for

```
May 11 08:37:47 ubuntu casper-md5check[3924]: Checking ./boot/grub/loopback.cfg...../boot/grub/loopback.cfg: OK
May 11 08:37:47 ubuntu casper-md5check[3924]: Check finished: no errors found.
May 11 08:37:47 ubuntu systemd[1]: Finished casper-md5check.service - casper-md5check Verify Live ISO checksums.
```

This validation I believe is essential, as I find 5-8% of ISO writes fail regardless of the hardware being used (ie. *different boxes & different thumb-drives*).

**Question**

Can I validate the ISO write using an easy tool, using the same box I used to write it (ie. *no reboot or nearby box necessary*).

My preference is terminal; as it's where I am for these tasks.

Comment: Likely obvious.. but this is an *engineered* question, asked to help publish a new tool... All answers of course are welcome, and sorry if it's a *duplicate* (*I didn't find a question, but I may have used the wrong terms!*).  @sudodus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Tool to check that cloning was successful

Cloning from an image file, typically an iso file, to a USB drive is considered a robust process, but sometimes it fails. Maybe this is caused by problems with buffering when a big iso file is cloned to a pendrive with slow memory cells, maybe caused by flaky memory cells.

Anyway, I see that we need a convenient way to check that cloning was successful, so I created a small shellscript.

`diff-image-drive` makes it easy to check by means of comparing the sha256sums.

- [The original version can be copied and pasted from here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1958073&page=62&p=14142699#post14142699)
- [An upgraded version can be copied and pasted from here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1958073&page=62&p=14142910#post14142910)

---

#### Demo using the original version of the shellscript:

At first there is some previous content in the target device, an SSD connected via a USB to SATA adapter:

```
$ sudo diff-image-drive mantic-desktop-amd64.iso /dev/sdc
 Comparing content of 'mantic-desktop-amd64.iso' and '/dev/sdc' 
partprobe: 
umount /dev/sdc*: 
done - no partition mounted on /dev/sdc 
 calculating sha256sums ...
2,92GiB 0:00:18 [ 163MiB/s] [================================================================>] 100%            
file:   cdfaafb6be7b4b183b43bf395f7a1e12b14bcc6914c13ca8246a4cb00254ef6e  -
2,92GiB 0:00:14 [ 203MiB/s] [================================================================>] 100%            
device: ac65f5bb93207976cf59e4440147ffdda40e6e0ac3a3f964f525c0063660b51d  -
 content of iso/img file and device differ
```

After cloning from the mantic iso file to the target device:

```
$ sudo diff-image-drive mantic-desktop-amd64.iso /dev/sdc
 Comparing content of 'mantic-desktop-amd64.iso' and '/dev/sdc' 
partprobe: 
Warning: Not all of the space available to /dev/sdc appears to be used, you can fix the GPT to use all of the space (an extra 462737388 blocks) or continue with the current setting? 
umount /dev/sdc*: 
done - no partition mounted on /dev/sdc 
 calculating sha256sums ...
2,92GiB 0:00:14 [ 208MiB/s] [================================================================>] 100%            
file:   cdfaafb6be7b4b183b43bf395f7a1e12b14bcc6914c13ca8246a4cb00254ef6e  -
2,92GiB 0:00:14 [ 204MiB/s] [================================================================>] 100%            
device: cdfaafb6be7b4b183b43bf395f7a1e12b14bcc6914c13ca8246a4cb00254ef6e  -
 content of iso/img file and device match
```

In this case you need not worry about the warning from partprobe. A drive cloned from an iso file does not care about what is behind the cloned field.

#### Screenshots using version 1.3 of the shellscript:

The color high-lighting is there also in the original version, but checking when skipping head/tail is new. This helps checking when a drive cloned from an Ubuntu iso file has been used (so that a 'writable' partition was created).

[image]

Checking directly after cloning.

---

[image]

Checking after the drive was booted into.

---

You can find more details via [this post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1958073&page=62&p=14142699#post14142699) and the following posts to my thread at the Ubuntu Forums.