# Ubuntu boot error with squashfs

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I am trying to dual boot Ubuntu 23.04 with Windows 11 in my HP Omen  laptop16 with AMD Ryzen 7 7840HS with rtx 4060. I ran into this error.

[image]

I also have disabled Secure Boot, disabled the nouveau driver. I also verify with the ISO I downloaded with sha hash to ensure it is the correct image. I also used different USBs, but the error is still there. What should I do now?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is verifying ISOs downloaded from the official website worthwhile?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993407/is-verifying-isos-downloaded-from-the-official-website-worthwhile)

Comment: Did you verify your ISO? I gather you did. Otherwise it's a write of the ISO to media that failed; you mention multiple writes but did you use a method appropriate for your ISO? ie. some older software only writes Ubuntu ISOs up to 20.04 (*not later such as 23.04) so if using a re-format ISO & older software can create issues. If i have issues with booting a thumb-drive on one box; I use two other boxes to confirm the validity of the ISO write, ie. a somewhat similar box to boot & confirm ISO check occurred; then a very different box - if valid on both those boxes I assume box specific issue

Comment: Yes, I verify the ISO and it is the correct one. I use both Balena and Rufus to create bootable usb but still no luck. Also, I try with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and the error is still the same.

Comment: You gave no version details on balena or rufus... Did you read the `rufus` docs; as releases >20.04 (esp. 23.04) can have problems with older versions IF not written with specific options (ie. pure *cloning* will work on all versions, but the re-format options mean you need updated version of `rufus` to write newer releases; ie. you a version of rufus created after release of 23.04!).

Comment: Well, I both use the lastest Rufus 4.2 version and the lastest Balena. This issue also happens when I try to boot with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS too.

Comment: I don't know your issue, but Ubuntu 22.04 LTS isn't very specific; as you gave no product details (Server uses an older stack being the most stable (5.15 kernel only), where Desktop has 3 downloadable stacks available (22.04 & 22.04.1 Desktop use 5.15 kernel, 22.04.2 uses 5.19 & 22.04.3 using 6.2 though not officially released yet); and you gave no details.  As previously stated I'd use other boxes to confirm media is perfect (*as it can take <2 mins its a good insurance policy in my view as rules out the obvious reason for squashfs errors!*)

Comment: Well, I instaill Ubuntu Desktop. Do you know how to check whether the bootable usb is corrupt or not? The ISO I download is verified but I don't know how I can verify bootable usb.

Comment: I already provided a link which has an answer on **Media Checks**...  In (my) answer on it it states "*Modern releases (20.04 and later) automatically scan...*" and includes a section for 23.04  (*see my first comment!*) which is what I'd have performed on other boxes as already stated (*a like box and different box is what I usually use; but I have access to >25 boxes for QA purposes*)

Comment: But I create bootable usb in Window not Ubuntu. In your answer, it seems like checking media in Ubuntu. Is there any solution in Window?

Comment: Tools exist; eg. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1467825/validating-an-iso-write-directly-after-writing/1467884#1467884 but sorry I'm not aware of any such tool in windows, as I'd not use it.