# Computer won’t boot into install drive, shows error

Tags: drivers, system-installation, usb-installation

So I tried installing Ubuntu with the 23.10 desktop iso with an usb drive flashed with balenaEtcher. I boot up my computer from this drive, and get this error before even getting the option to try or install Ubuntu:

```
[7.940771] UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in /build/linux-D15vQj/linux-6.5.0/drivers/gpu/drm/amd/amdgpu/../pm/powerplay/humgr/processpptables.C:929:40
[    7.940872] index 1 is out of range for type
'UCHAR [1] '
[    7.981679] ============================================
```

Is it possible to fix this, or is my gpu simply incompatible? If there’s a way to fix this without changing hardware, it would be great since I am trying to install Ubuntu on a laptop, so it would mean changing my cpu, which I don’t want to do because I would be way too expensive to change if it is not soldered to the motherboard, which I highly doubt.

Comment: Did you verify the ISO?  or verify write of ISO to your media?  You can use another device to perform this check.  You mention release (23.10) but give no clues as to which ISO (two exist for Ubuntu Desktop 23.10, one for Ubuntu Server 23.10 etc..)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is verifying ISOs downloaded from the official website worthwhile?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993407/is-verifying-isos-downloaded-from-the-official-website-worthwhile)  Also useful maybe https://askubuntu.com/questions/1467825/validating-an-iso-write-directly-after-writing