Ubuntu Studio boot from live usb failed: "Initramfs unpacking failed"
Booting Ubuntu Studio 24.04 from live USB freezes and gives the error:
"Initramfs unpacking failed: invalid magic at the start of compressed archive"
Unlike other posts, this is not from an installed system, but trying to boot from a live USB.
The iso sha256 is OK, and booting from the stick on an Intel Nuc works fine, so the problem is not with the USB stick.
Here are the relevant bits from my system:
    Machine:
  Type: Desktop System: wortmann product: N/A v: N/A serial: R3046492
  Mobo: ASUSTeK model: P8H61-M LE/USB3 v: Rev x.0x serial: MF70C4G00803046
    BIOS: American Megatrends v: 4601 date: 09/18/2013
CPU:
  Info: quad core model: Intel Core i5-3350P bits: 64 type: MCP cache:
    L2: 1024 KiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 1599 min/max: 1600/3300 cores: 1: 1600 2: 1600 3: 1600
    4: 1596
  Flags: acpi aes aperfmperf apic arat arch_perfmon avx bts clflush cmov
    constant_tsc cpuid cpuid_fault cx16 cx8 de ds_cpl dtes64 dtherm dts epb
    erms est f16c flush_l1d fpu fsgsbase fxsr ht ibpb ibrs ida lahf_lm lm mca
    mce md_clear mmx monitor msr mtrr nonstop_tsc nopl nx pae pat pbe pcid
    pclmulqdq pdcm pebs pge pln pni popcnt pse pse36 pti pts rdrand rdtscp
    rep_good sep smep ss ssbd sse sse2 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 stibp syscall tm
    tm2 tsc tsc_deadline_timer vme x2apic xsave xsaveopt xtopology xtpr
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA GK104 [GeForce GTX 680] driver: nouveau v: kernel
  Device-2: Sonix QHD Webcam type: USB driver: snd-usb-audio,uvcvideo
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.7 driver: X: loaded: modesetting
    unloaded: fbdev,vesa dri: nouveau gpu: nouveau resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz
  API: OpenGL v: 4.3 Mesa 22.3.6 renderer: NVE4
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel 6 Series/C200 Series Family High Definition Audio
    driver: snd_hda_intel
  Device-2: NVIDIA GK104 HDMI Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  Device-3: Sonix QHD Webcam type: USB driver: snd-usb-audio,uvcvideo
  Device-4: M-Audio Fast Track MKII type: USB driver: snd-usb-audio
  API: ALSA v: k6.1.0-17-amd64 status: kernel-api
  Server-1: PulseAudio v: 16.1 status: active (root, process)
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet
    driver: r8169
  IF: enp3s0 state: down mac: c8:60:00:d1:1c:68
  Device-2: ASUSTek Realtek 8188EUS [USB-N10 Nano] type: USB driver: r8188eu
  IF: wlx7c10c973eb28 state: up mac: 7c:10:c9:73:eb:28
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 1.02 TiB used: 476.56 GiB (45.7%)
  ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Seagate model: ST31000524AS size: 931.51 GiB
  ID-2: /dev/sdb vendor: Kingston model: SV300S37A120G size: 111.79 GiB
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 108.54 GiB used: 50.63 GiB (46.6%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sdb1
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: partition size: 975 MiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) dev: /dev/sdb5
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 29.0 C mobo: N/A gpu: nouveau temp: 41.0 C
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A gpu: nouveau fan: 1080


Did you verify ISO after download? and write ISO correctly to media (as per documentation; and without reformat of ISO) as the error you mention is often the consequence of a badly re-format of ISO (use default clone write as per doco).  I'd use another box to verify media (assuming you did the ISO validation check as media validation can't be trusted unless ISO is valid)

I wrote:
"The iso sha256 is OK, and booting from the stick on a Intel Nuc works fine, so the problem is not with the usb stick"
Since it works with the Intel NUC, the problem I reckon can't be with the stick.

On the other machine you said it worked on (Intel NUC) did you look at the log showing the media check completed??  ie. use that other machine to confirm the ISO was written correctly to media (see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1311183/do-i-need-to-check-the-integrity-of-a-ubuntu-install) though you can do that with software post-write too (or did you do that??)   Your "it works on intel nuc thus its fine" is valid if Intel NUC has identical hardware to the machine you're testing on; is it identical hardware?? as you don't state that (thus same kernel/kernel modules etc used)

No the hardware is not identical.
I just have a hard time believing the usb stick is corrupted, when it boots and runs with zero problems on the Nuc.
sha256 says the iso is fine, what specific command should I try to see if the stick is corrupted one way or another regardless?

You can look at this question/answer (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1467825/validating-an-iso-write-directly-after-writing) for details of a tool that validates a recently written ISO.. but there are many such tools. If you don't have a tool already installed; I'd just use another machine as per answer I already provided (ie. read the logs as booting the ISO triggers a media check, so read the result of that media check from that boot on other hardware as already stated).

OK thanks, I'll try that with the Nuc in a few minutes.

I finally solved it, the usb stick was not corrupted, the ISO-image was fine.
Instead of choosing "UEFI: Verbatim" from my BIOS, I chose "Verbatim" thus without UEFI and the machine nicely booted from my USB stick and I was able to install Ubuntu Studio 24.04 without any hickups.
