What format to use for bootable usb for a mac?
I followed this tutorial https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#1-overview. When I run ubuntu, or attempt to, it doesn't register the mac's mouse or keyboard. I had to get a pc keyboard and mouse, and then still can't get it to work. It keeps locking up. Anyway. The computer no longer registers the usb. I wanted to erase and try again. Can't. So ... I am going to buy a new ssd, but what format should I use? I think the one said in the tutorial isn't the correct one. If it is than I have no idea what went wrong.

You don't format a USB before writing an ISO to it, as the ISO contains a formatted image that overwrites whatever is on the USB-thumb-drive if written correctly. If you reformat the ISO during write (to change the format), you risk the install not working, or the thumb-drive not even being bootable due to changes made; so I suggest following the official tutorials. You didn't mention Ubuntu product/release, so we can't know if you used an appropriate tutorial. If you want to be sure validate ISO write https://askubuntu.com/questions/1467825/validating-an-iso-write-directly-after-writing etc

Providing details of your mac will also allow us to better help you; did you start with an appropriate Ubuntu ISO for your unstated MAC hardware?  as multiple Ubuntu products & architecture ISOs exist, just as there are multiple variations in apple MAC hardware (though fewer than what Ubuntu provides for)

This question is similar to: How do I get my Mac to boot from an Ubuntu USB key?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I loaded ubuntu -latest version- on a new Seagate and it is working; except it doesn't register the mouse or keyboard. The setting panel says: need plug in for blue tooth. How do I address this? imac, late-2015 desktop. I also think I need to use the Seagate differently. Can I erase and do a partition? It's 2TB. If so, can you give me a link for how to erase and reset this Seagate? To clarify, I can't turn the blue tooth switch.

The latest Ubuntu release was Ubuntu Core 24 released this month (June 2024); is that what you're using? as that is intended to be used headless or without keyboard/screen.  If you mean something else, please be specific (eg. I suspect you were using an earlier Ubuntu 24.04 Server/Desktop release; but you do say latest which is Ubuntu Core 24 or the snap version of Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Server).  Be precise & clear with details.
