# How to "test-run" Kubuntu 23.10 from DVD

Tags: system-installation, kubuntu

When trying to boot to a recently downloaded DVD
Kubuntu 23.10 "Mantic Manticore"
we're shown these choices:

```
    Try or Install Kubuntu
    Kubuntu (safe graphics)
    OEM install (for manufacturers)
    Test memory

Use the (U) & (D) keys to select which entry is highlighted
Press enter to boot the selected OS, 'e' to edit the commands 
before booting or 'c' for a command-line.
```

We immediately had choices:

- First, are we "trying" or "installing"?
- Second, what exactly is meant by "safe graphics"?
- "OEM install" didn't seem appropriate in this instance,
  but we tested the memory anyway, since it's been a long time
  since having done so (it tested fine).

  Then:
  "Attempt interactive netboot from a URL? yes no (default yes:)"

  On answering "yes" it proceeded to download a few thousand
  files and began to look more like an install than a trial,
  and we canceled out (Ctrl-Alt-Del).

WHEN do we get to choose WHICH we want, "Try" or "Install"?

Beyond that, there's a lot of questions for which I have no
answers.  I know just enough cli to get me in trouble.

Is there a safe, SIMPLE way to "Try" this distribution?

Comment: Just try "Try or Install" and you will find out.

Comment: Use the "*Try or Install*" option as @muru suggested, which will boot it in *try* mode.  Install is mentioned in the menu item as you can elect to install whilst running it in *try* mode.  FYI: Boot the installation media from USB thumb-drive is *easier* than trying it from *optical* (DVD) media.  The "Attempt interactive netboot from a URL? yes no (default yes:)" message implies your *optical* media is invalid; did you check it prior to write?

Comment: Maybe helpful is https://askubuntu.com/questions/1311183/do-i-need-to-check-the-integrity-of-a-ubuntu-install  where your messages likely included "*Unable to find a medium container*" thus the offer to download it & message you report having; which is a consequence of invalid ISO download, OR invalid write of ISO to your install media (DVD). See https://askubuntu.com/questions/993407/is-verifying-isos-downloaded-from-the-official-website-worthwhile for ISO validation info

Comment: @guiverc Thank you!  I do seem to have a problem with the installed DVD device to solve!

Comment: DVD or *optical* media was an expected install media up to 20.04, but not for 20.10 or later releases. Yes some QA is still performed to ensure it works (*on new hardware, new & fast DVD*), but the media verification process used by 20.10 & later can have *timeout* issues on older drives & thus data is rejected (optical drives respond too slowly), including with *snap* packages which create unhelpful error messages. You can re-try it; I found about 1 in 3 installs from DVD worked on my QA test hardware (old not new) but I'd recommend cheap USB thumb-drive as is now expected (for 100% success)