# Lubuntu - Network Manager Widget Closes Immediately After Open

Tags: lubuntu, network-manager, lenovo, panel, lxqt

**Problem:**

When I (right) click to open the Network Manager from the panel (in the bottom right), it opens for 0.5-2s before closing. This seems to be independent of mouse movement or clicking. This means it is difficult to use the options in the menu (but if I am fast enough, I can still use them).

I am clicking the Network widget that appears after enabling Network on Autostart (below). I believe the nm-tray widget works as expected (the one that displays "enable Wi-Fi" works fine, the one that lists the available Wi-Fi connections does not work).

---

**My computer spec:**

Running lubuntu-22.04.3-desktop-amd64 on a Z50-70 Laptop (Lenovo) - Type 80E7. (Only Lubuntu, no other OS, though the laptop used to use Windows 8)

The laptop is quite old, and has battery issues (evidenced by weak battery pop-ups).

**Other:**

Prior to this, I enabled Network on Autostart (through Preferences -> LXQt Settings -> Session Settings -> Autostart -> Network) so that the Network Manager would appear on the panel. Network has an exclamation mark next to it.

The image download was not corrupted, as I checked the SHA256SUM of the iso file I got the same as the reference on Ubuntu's website:
ffccfa53a10bacf0b8b7589e85c739e650aef8f38ac4ed66f96fd591396d2f21 *lubuntu-22.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso.

I am new to running Linux in general. The issue has been present since the installation of Lubuntu (which was only a few days ago).

---

**Testing:**

- Waiting after right-clicking: it still closes.
- Other panel items behave as expected (i.e. Removable Media, Volume Control, Notifications, Battery, Qlipper, World Clock, etc)
- Opened a terminal (Ctrl + Alt + t), ran nm-connection-editor, it doesn't seem to provide any diagnostic output - just "Wired connection 1" and a Wi-Fi network I am trying to connect to. (i.e. the command succeeded)
- Opened Computer/var/crash/ and it was empty.

Comment: AFAIK the applet associated with the network button is `nm-connection-editor` - have you tried running that from a terminal (LXTerminal or QTerminal) and if so does that provide additional diagnostic output?

Comment: The widget on the panel is [`nm-tray`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/nm-tray), which on clicking *Edit Connections* will open `nm-connection-editor` as @steeldriver suggests. I'd too suggest trying to open it via Qterminal as already suggested & look for clues; as well as explore `/var/crash/` for any crash file indications (or system logs). I have more failures on the write of ISO to media that download of ISO (ie. checksum of ISO only checks download). Do other panel items behave as expected? (ie. only `nm-tray` closing).

Comment: @steeldriver Do you know what diagnostic output I should be expecting from running `nm-connection-editor`? Is there anything else (other than running the command in the terminal) that I should do to get diagnostics?

@guiverc How can I check whether the write of the ISO to media has failures? What should I be looking for in the system logs?

Comment: @RayaBuckley I'd expect some error messages *if the command failed* - however it sounds like it succeeded?

Comment: I've [written answers to this question on this site](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993407/is-verifying-isos-downloaded-from-the-official-website-worthwhile/993409#993409) where a non-upvoted answer (*added much later*) has me showing how I perform media checks prior to starting an install (also can be read [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1311183/do-i-need-to-check-the-integrity-of-a-ubuntu-install))... if your install already exists though its a bit late. `nm-connection-editor` is a Connections Editor tool & isn't used to connect, just change settings (gear icon), or + (add) or - (rm)

Comment: To search logs; I'd likely work out what network hardware you're using (`sudo lshw -C network`) so I had keywords to search. and then explore from there .. ie. on this desktop my NIC shows "*logical name: enp0s31f6*" so I can `sudo dmesg |grep enp0s31f7` to see some results, or even `sudo journactl |grep enp0s31f6` for starters, though I'd probably page & search using POSIX search tools  (as `journactl` shows human time, you can search for messages around when you have issues such as when you clicked the tool & that's how I'd expect to find useful detail; `dmesg` useful if you just tried too!)