Cannot install fresh Ubuntu-studio 24.04
I'm trying to install a fresh copy of ubuntu-studio 24.04 but as soon as I click on the installer , it crashes after few seconds. If I connect to Wifi and re-launch the installer I manage to go to the copying files phase but after few seconds this phase starts, the installer crashes again.
How can I solve this?
Thanks in advance.

Make sure to verify the downloaded ISO file.

Have you explored logs to see what the actual issue is...  With what you describe, I'd first ensure you validated your ISO!! prior to write to media, and ensure the media write was successful (if you didn't do this; I wouldn't worry, just ensure the media check completed successfully by reading logs of your live session prior to starting installer; this can be trusted if ISO check was performed).

Does this answer your question? Is verifying ISOs downloaded from the official website worthwhile?  but maybe also see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1311183/do-i-need-to-check-the-integrity-of-a-ubuntu-install

what works for me is just disable the internet (WIFI) during the setup phase and everything is fine so seems like there is a possible timeout or recurring issue in these repose for some regions, may be disabling the internet will help to complete setup

I check and the iso file is correct but the problem remains :-(

Disabling WiFi allowed the installation to proceed. Tried a dozen times prior to following this simple advice. Thank you Abdul Hameed.

I fixed the problem using Ubuntustudio (safe graphics) from the starting boot menu of the installation media.

Obviously the best answer. After doing that the process started smoothly and I was able to display the logs.

I would also recommend using a wired connection, just to be sure.

A common cause of the Ubuntu installer freezing partway through is defective sectors on the hard disk. Swapping the hard disk with another hard disk will fix this problem. It depends on the specfic hardware problem. If it's a problem with the hard disk sometimes it will cause an Ubuntu installation to fail,  and sometimes it won't.
If you want to rerun the Ubuntu installer from the beginning simply remove the Ubuntu live USB, turn off the computer, and restart the computer with the Ubuntu live USB inserted in a USB port.

I try to install kubuntu and everything works fine. It it was a hw problem also kubuntu install should fail... or not?

It depends on the hardware problem. If it's a problem with the hard disk sometimes it will cause an Ubuntu installation to fail and sometimes it won't.

You may want to try a desktop version of the installer and check your hardware. Seems like you have something hardware related causing a kernel panic or "crash". Check "lshw" and dmesg for any screams for help. Be sure to unplug all USB and peripherals before installing. Once installed you can plug them in one at a time and install any additional kernel modules or drivers. That's the process I've used to find incompatible devices which cause issues.

I try to install kubuntu and everything works fine. It it was a hw problem also kubuntu install should fail... or not?
