# Problems installing Ubuntu on 2015 windows 10 laptop

Tags: boot

I'm new at this and have never installed Linux before. Every time that I try to install using a USB drive that I formatted with Rufus, it results in the error "/init: line 49: can't open /dev/sr0/: no medium found" and refuses to install and boot. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: From the error message either the ISO was invalid (did you verify it? https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0) or the write to installation media failed (did you verify it?  how this is done varies on release which you didn't say, so verify using the appropriate method for your *unstated* release).  In my experience it's mostly the write to installation media that fails.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is verifying ISOs downloaded from the official website worthwhile?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993407/is-verifying-isos-downloaded-from-the-official-website-worthwhile)

Comment: Please note my first comment, in my experience it's more the write to media that is faulty (and that's from writing 150-380 ISOs to media per year) than the ISO being downloaded incorrectly.. but it's the first item to check. You didn't provide release details, but SR0 refers to your installation media not being found! meaning it was faulty (ie. did you verify it?) or badly written to your installation media (and thus faulty).

Comment: Sorry for late response I have verified the ISO, what next?

Comment: As I said, the next step is to verify the write of the ISO to your installation media. As stated you didn't provide any release details, so I can't provide the appropriate link/details for that, as how you verify varies on Ubuntu release (which I don't know).

Comment: OK I downloaded 20.04 LTS

Answer (score 1):

For creating Ubuntu install media from windows, use [win32diskimager](https://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/) as per the [Ubuntu website](https://ubuntu.com/download/iot/installation-media). Most distro's can be written using [balena etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/), it will verify if it imaged the USB correctly or not which is the #1 issue usually with bad installs. If you insist on Rufus, 95% of the time you should always use DD mode to image the drive. In the future, if you're still using Linux, or even Mac for that matter, use the dd command as it gets the job done every time and it's very simple.

Comment: I used Balena and it says that the flash failed on the drive. Should I try a different drive?

Comment: @NonambulatoryCat Yes, you should.

Comment: +1 but it should be added that Balena Etcher can also be used in Windows or OSX and it doesn't mention the great MKUSB for Ubuntu/Debian. Both use DD and are a lot safer than running the command directly.