# Is ubuntu cdimage site, which is http, secure?

Tags: security, downloads, https, cd-image

Ubuntu's cdimage site is http,

Is it safe to download from [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-base/releases/)?

(because it is not https, that is why I'm asking)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's safe to download from there, as even if you suffer a MiTM attack, the checksum validation will detect your image is flawed and so it doesn't matter  (you can use [`zsync`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ZsyncCdImage) to correct it).

Myself, I often download from my local mirror (faster & it used to be quota free when downloaded from my ISPs mirror), then verified their copy by comparing the calculated checksum obtained from the main site.

(*these days I usually `zsync` a download; so by downloading only the differences from another ISO I already have; the percentage of the ISO I download is usually 85-95% complete when I start; ie. if I want Xubuntu; I may start with the Ubuntu ISO if I have it for the same release; or a similar release.  `zsync` also validates the ISO at the end of the download*)

CD mirrors can be found at https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+cdmirrors

How to validate your ISO after download can be found at https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0

Comment: Also related - [Is verifying ISOs download worthwhile](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993407/is-verifying-isos-downloaded-from-the-official-website-worthwhile/993409#993409)