# Issues Installing 20.04 on ASUS Laptop

Tags: system-installation

New to Linux and am trying to install on my ASUS GL502VM laptop in a partitioned section of my HDD, I have dug through a bunch of posts and done these things;

- Disabled Fast Boot in BIOS
- Disabled Secure Boot in BIOS
- Install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on a USB drive via Rufus following every step on itsfoss

Get to GRUB GNU, select Ubuntu and get;

[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnB67.jpg)

If I go through that prompt it just says;

`No DHCPOFFERS received. No working leases in persisten database - sleeping.no search or nameservers found in /run/net-*.conf`

Comment: Your ISO was either faulty (did you verify it? (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0) or the write to media was faulty thus the "*Unable to find a medium...*" error message & offer to download the ISO (since your ISO was detected as being flawed)...   See https://askubuntu.com/questions/993407/is-verifying-isos-downloaded-from-the-official-website-worthwhile/993409#993409   Note: in my experience the write to thumb-drive media is most at fault (*5-8% failure is the norm*) but you should start with ISO validation first

Comment: That tutorial didn't help, end up getting

Comment: That tutorial didn't help, when I get to "Retrieve correct signature key" step in the tutorial and enter;   
`gpg --keyid-format long --verify SHA256SUMS.gpg SHA256SUMS`   
It just says no such or directory exist instead of giving ID numbers to download. I did confirm what I could through Rufus itself though. Just picked up a new USB and am going to attempt that now.   
-EDIT-  That seems to have worked! Thanks