# Can't boot from live usb. SQUASHFS error: failed to read block

Tags: boot, live-usb, squashfs

I'm having trouble booting from a live USB of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. This is what it says:

```
SQUASHFS error: Failed to read block 0x5afbbf2f: -5
```

Would anyone be able to help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is verifying ISOs downloaded from the official website worthwhile?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993407/is-verifying-isos-downloaded-from-the-official-website-worthwhile)

Comment: There are two answers in that question by me; the second one contains an answer on *squashfs* errors which are error on your installation media; ie. either you didn't verify the ISO **or** your write of ISO to installation media was invalid...  In my experience it's the write to thumb-drive that's faulty (*thumb-drives are cheap consumables made to cost*)

Comment: I will try it later, thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)

Answer (score -1):

Temp workaround: add to grub line: all_generic_ide pci=nommconf