# Ubuntu 22 LTS crashing with iwlwifi errors in logs, hard reboot required

Tags: drivers, kernel, 22.04, freeze

I have used this MSI katana computer for 2 months with no issue.
Installed WINE and installed NVIDIA Drivers to be able to use Steam, which was installed but I hadn't run yet. The computer started freezing randomly. No pattern to when it freezes.(Log in, desktop, in Chrome, in Steam, with just terminal open, etc)

`SysRq + REISUB` doesn't work, `Alt+F2` doesn't open dialog, `CTRL+ALT+F3` doesn't open TTY, so a hard shutdown is necessary.

Uninstalled Ubuntu 22 LTS
Installed Ubuntu 20 LTS and had the same problem.
Uninstalled Ubuntu 20 and reinstalled Ubuntu 22.

Did the updates during and after reinstall via terminal.
Restarted the computer and checked the logs. There were errors with nouveau on boot. Installed NVIDIA recommended driver.
Downloaded and opened Steam, with one Chrome tab running.
Computer froze.

The hardware logs after last hard shutdown:

> 15:06:27 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: iwl_trans_reclaim bad
> state = 0  
> 15:06:27 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: failed to
> idle channel 0 [DRM] 
> 15:06:23 kernel: ieee80211 phy0: Hardware
> restart was requested  
> 15:06:23 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:
> WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 4 fired (delay=0ms).  
> 15:06:23
> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 4
> fired (delay=0ms).  
> 15:06:23 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:
> 0x0000025B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR  
> 15:06:23
> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x05B0905B |
> CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM  
> 15:06:23 kernel: iwlwifi
> 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300504 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP  
> 15:06:23 kernel:
> iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP  
> 15:06:23
> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300504 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID  
> 15:06:23
> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID  
> 15:06:23
> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
>
> 15:06:23 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 |
> FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION 
> 15:06:23 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:
> 0x0000A482 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION  
> 15:06:23 kernel: iwlwifi
> 0000:00:14.3: 0x00090006 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION 
> 15:06:23
> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80290033 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
>
> 15:06:23 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x60000000 |
> FSEQ_ERROR_CODE  
> 15:06:23 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq
> Registers:  
> 15:06:23 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000080 |
> IML/ROM WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0  
> 15:06:23 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:
> 0x00005B02 | IML/ROM data1  
> 15:06:23 kernel: iwlwifi
> 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | IML/ROM error/state  
> 15:06:23 kernel:
> iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: IML/ROM dump:  
> 15:06:23 kernel: iwlwifi
> 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000004 | isr status reg  
> 15:06:23 kernel:
> iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00B5010D | last host cmd  
> 15:06:23
> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0887F3C | stack pointer
>
> 15:06:23 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x051EBD73 | frame pointer
>
> 15:06:23 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xF1C864E0 | umac minor
>
> 15:06:23 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000042 | umac major
>
> 15:06:23 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac data3
>
> 15:06:23 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0080964 | umac data2
>
> 15:06:23 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000000 | umac data1
>
> 15:06:23 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0080964 | umac
> interruptlink2  
> 15:06:23 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8047430E
> | umac interruptlink1  
> 15:06:23 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:
> 0x80455AE6 | umac branchlink2  
> 15:06:23 kernel: iwlwifi
> 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1  
> 15:06:23 kernel:
> iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000066 | NMI_INTERRUPT_HOST  
> 15:06:23
> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x0000004A, valid: 7
>
> 15:06:23 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
>
> 15:06:23 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00009090 | flow_handler
>
> 15:06:23 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | timestamp
>
> 15:06:23 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000009 | lmpm_pmg_sel
>
> 15:06:23 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000000E7 |
> l2p_addr_match  
> 15:06:23 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000
> | l2p_mhvalid  
> 15:06:23 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00018034
> | l2p_duration  
> 15:06:23 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00004A88
> | l2p_control  
> 15:06:23 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00012C82
> | wait_event  
> 15:06:23 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x9C6B009D |
> last cmd Id  
> 15:06:23 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 |
> isr4  
> 15:06:23 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00C3428C | isr3
>
> 15:06:23 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x08F0000A | isr2
>
> 15:06:23 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr1
>
> 15:06:23 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20028000 | isr0
>
> 15:06:23 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80C8FC04 | hcmd
>
> 15:06:23 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00C89004 | board version
>
> 15:06:23 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000351 | hw version
>
> 15:06:23 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xF1C864E0 | uCode version
> minor  
> 15:06:23 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000042 | uCode
> version major  
> 15:06:23 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000001
> | uCode revision type  
> 15:06:23 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:
> 0x051EBD75 | time gp2  
> 15:06:23 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:
> 0x00000000 | time gp1  
> 15:06:23 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:
> 0x0000002A | tsf hi  
> 15:06:23 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:
> 0x4B0560B4 | tsf low  
> 15:06:23 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:
> 0xC7C15F52 | beacon time  
> 15:06:23 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:
> 0x00000000 | data3  
> 15:06:23 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:
> 0x01000000 | data2  
> 15:06:23 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:
> 0x00012C82 | data1  
> 15:06:23 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:
> 0x004C183E | interruptlink2  
> 15:06:23 kernel: iwlwifi
> 0000:00:14.3: 0x004C183E | interruptlink1  
> 15:06:23 kernel:
> iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004CB01A | branchlink2  
> 15:06:23 kernel:
> iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1  
> 15:06:23
> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A200 | trm_hw_status0
>
> 15:06:23 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000084 |
> NMI_INTERRUPT_UNKNOWN        
> 15:06:23 kernel: iwlwifi
> 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 66.f1c864e0.0
> QuZ-a0-hr-b0-66.ucode  
> 15:06:23 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:
> Transport status: 0x0000004A, valid: 6 
> 15:06:23 kernel: iwlwifi
> 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:  
> 15:06:23 kernel: iwlwifi
> 0000:00:14.3: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x1.
>
> 15:06:23 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Queue 5 is stuck 67 36
>
> 15:06:06 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: timer: stalled at
> ffffffffffffffff  
> 15:06:06 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: timer:
> stalled at ffffffffffffffff  
> 15:06:06 kernel: nouveau
> 0000:01:00.0: timer: stalled at ffffffffffffffff  
> 15:06:06
> kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: timer: stalled at ffffffffffffffff
>
> 15:06:06 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: timer: stalled at
> ffffffffffffffff  
> 15:06:06 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: timer:
> stalled at ffffffffffffffff  
> 15:06:06 kernel: nouveau
> 0000:01:00.0: timer: stalled at ffffffffffffffff  
> 15:06:06
> kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: timer: stalled at ffffffffffffffff
>
> 15:06:06 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: timer: stalled at
> ffffffffffffffff  
> 15:06:06 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: timer:
> stalled at ffffffffffffffff  
> 15:06:06 kernel: nouveau
> 0000:01:00.0: timer: stalled at ffffffffffffffff  
> 15:05:50
> kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: failed to idle channel 0 [DRM]
>
> 15:05:29 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: timer: stalled at
> ffffffffffffffff  
> 15:05:29 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: timer:
> stalled at ffffffffffffffff  
> 15:05:28 kernel: nouveau
> 0000:01:00.0: timer: stalled at ffffffffffffffff  
> 15:05:28
> kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: timer: stalled at ffffffffffffffff
>
> 15:05:28 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: timer: stalled at
> ffffffffffffffff  
> 15:05:28 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: timer:
> stalled at ffffffffffffffff  
> 15:05:28 kernel: nouveau
> 0000:01:00.0: timer: stalled at ffffffffffffffff  
> 15:05:28
> kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: timer: stalled at ffffffffffffffff
>
> 15:05:28 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: timer: stalled at
> ffffffffffffffff  
> 15:05:27 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: timer:
> stalled at ffffffffffffffff  
> 15:05:27 kernel: nouveau
> 0000:01:00.0: timer: stalled at ffffffffffffffff  
> 15:05:27
> kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: timer: stalled at ffffffffffffffff
>
> 15:05:27 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: timer: stalled at
> ffffffffffffffff  
> 15:05:27 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: timer:
> stalled at ffffffffffffffff  
> 15:05:27 kernel: nouveau
> 0000:01:00.0: timer: stalled at ffffffffffffffff  
> 15:05:27
> kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: failed to idle channel 0 [DRM]
>
> 15:05:10 kernel: logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:400A.0005: HID++
> 2.0 device connected.  
> 15:05:03 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: mc: intr 00000040

(lines 107 - 1986 repeats : 15:05:03 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: mc: intr 00000040)

> 15:04:56 kernel: r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: Link is Down
>
> 15:04:56 kernel: skl_hda_dsp_generic skl_hda_dsp_generic:
> hda_dsp_hdmi_build_controls: no PCM in topology for HDMI converter 3
>
> 15:04:56 kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek ehdaudio0D0: ASoC: source
> widget AIF1RX overwritten 
> 15:04:56 kernel:
> sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: ASoC: Parent card not yet
> available, widget card binding deferred 
> 15:04:56 kernel: Generic
> FE-GE Realtek PHY r8169-0-300:00: attached PHY driver
> (mii_bus:phy_addr=r8169-0-300:00, irq=MAC) 
> 15:04:56 kernel:
> sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: unknown sof_ext_man header type
> 3 size 0x30 
> 15:04:56 kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] fb0:
> i915drmfb frame buffer device 
> 15:04:55 kernel: iwlwifi
> 0000:00:14.3 wlo1: renamed from wlan0 
> 15:04:55 kernel: nouveau
> 0000:01:00.0: DRM: MM: using COPY for buffer copies 
> 15:04:55
> kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: Digital mics found on Skylake+
> platform, using SOF driver 
> 15:04:55 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:
> Detected RF HR B5, rfid=0x10a100 
> 15:04:55 kernel: nouveau
> 0000:01:00.0: bios: version 94.07.32.00.23

Open to any suggestions for how to fix the freezing / avoid hard shutdown.

Comment: Are you sure that the Live Media was good? Here are 2 links for you to look at. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview

Comment: I downloaded the ISO image from [releases.ubuntu.com](http://releases.ubuntu.com) When I follow the gpg verification link you posted, I get   :  gpg: can't open 'SHA256SUMS.gpg': No such file or directory
gpg: verify signatures failed: No such file or directory

Comment: Which means it got corrupted in the download.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is verifying ISOs downloaded from the official website worthwhile?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993407/is-verifying-isos-downloaded-from-the-official-website-worthwhile)

Comment: Please be precise with details; 22 & 22.04 are different Ubuntu products; 22 being a *flavor* of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server which is designed for *headless* operation so `wine` & Nvidia make no sense on a 22 system (they are 22.04 only).   Your 20 detail was of *little* value as you were missing details (were you trying a different? or the same kernel stack as 22.04?  You didn't say so identical results may have been expected but you gave no clear details, and details you did provide are unclear!)  Don't forget 5 stacks are available on 20.04 media (5.4, 5.8, 5.11, 5.13, 5.15 not counting OEM..)

Comment: @David, Thank you, I'll try redownloading the ISO image and making another.

Comment: @Guiveric, thank you for your feedback. I'm not a developer, just an ubuntu enthusiast trying my best. Your feedback gives me more things to test, much appreciated.