# Ubuntu reinstallation issue

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I had dual booted my laptop with the windows 11 and Ubuntu. I ran the “sudo rm -rf /*” command accidentally and after that my laptop is not listing any boot device and showing as please reinstall the OS. But when I tried to install the Ubuntu I am getting the following error.

“The installer encountered an error copying files to the hard disk:

[Errno 5] Input/output error

This is often due to a faulty CD/DVD disk or drive, or a faulty hard
disk. It may help to clean the CD/DVD, to burn the CD/DVD at a lower
speed, to clean the CD/DVD drive lens (cleaning kits are often
available from electronics suppliers), to check whether the hard disk
is old and in need of replacement, or to move the system to a cooler
environment.”

Can anyone please help me to resolve this?

Comment: whatever iso you used to create install media is incomplete - the I/O failure indicates either the ISO was bad (usually thats the prime cause) or the USB drive used for install was bad.

Comment: I had used the same usb before 1 month and it was working perfectly, also I tried with another iso image too.

Comment: What are you using to flash the ISO onto the USB drive? Do you have another port to test the USB on? Any firmware updates for the Laptop? Are you able to boot into Windows still?

Comment: The try Ubuntu works fine without any issue

Comment: @BobserLuck I used Rufus tool to make the iso as bootable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is verifying ISOs downloaded from the official website worthwhile?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993407/is-verifying-isos-downloaded-from-the-official-website-worthwhile)

Comment: Your *Try Ubuntu* test was only valid if you started every program on the media, plus used every function... as install will cause *almost* all to be read & installed to your disk, compared to a normal "Try" which uses only small portions...  Your installation media is faulty (referred to as CD/DVD in images); meaning it's been corrupted since it was last used for install OR different hardware is being used OR numerous other issues with it causing the faults.  Return to verifying ISO & re-write to media.  How you do this varies on product/release you didn't mention.

Comment: Also for installing the windows it is not showing the hard drive but in Ubuntu it is

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a few that will swear by Rufus. I haven't had the best of luck with it myself in the past. If you've got a working Windows machine, might try spinning up `diskpart` and then `select disk <USB Drive>` and do a good ol' `clean` in case there's an issue with the drive. **Make sure to select the propper drive**. You can check the label and/or size to verify.

Reference the checksum of the ISO if you're worried about initial ISO corruption.

Then try giving [Ventoy](https://www.ventoy.net/en/index.html) a shot.

If it is an issue with the installation media like [@Thomas Ward](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1439751/ubuntu-reinstallation-issue?noredirect=1#comment2512005_1439751) and [@Nmath](https://askubuntu.com/users/953371/nmath) have reccomended, the above should take care of it.

If you are still getting the same error after all that, there's a chance that  Intel's Rapid Storage Technology might be getting in the way.

If it's a fairly new laptop, and you're using an older version of Ubuntu, it might be giving you issues.

[Here's](https://help.ubuntu.com/rst/) a guide on how to manage it and help Windows use AHCI if you switch it over.

Granted, that's just a hunch based on the fact it's giving you IO error to your HD.