# Lubuntu/Xubuntu always freeze at some point (sometimes when installing) on a Dell Latitude 7490 (install to SD card)

Tags: xubuntu, lubuntu, 22.04, dell, freeze

I am trying to install Lubuntu 22.04 on the SD card drive (uSD 64 GB) of a Dell Latitude 7490. I can boot from the USB key, launch the installer, but it always freezes at some point. Sometimes it freezes early, while I am configuring the location, or keyboard, etc, and "at best" the install starts but soon freezes. This is not only the installer that is freezed but the whole PC: the OS is unresponsive and I have no other choice than shutting it down by pressing the power button.

I have tried with 2 different USB keys (old ones, but still working ones), 2 different USB ports, and I have even tried with the 20.04 installer. In all cases it freezes...

What could be wrong?

EDIT:

- as all Lubuntu installation trials were ending with a freeze at some point, I finally tried installing Xubuntu 22.04. It worked.
- I was quite happy, could boot on as newly installer SD card... and it freezed while I was applying the updates. I could no longer boot on the card, the filesystem was apparently corrupted.
- I reinstalled Xubuntu from scratch, booted again on the card, played a bit with the applications, browsed the web... and as soon as I launched the installation of the updates, it freezed again.

Notes:

- during the boot on the SD card I can see various error messages related to ACPI, or to the filesystem of the SD card (see below):
- `dmesg | grep mmc` reports the following error about the SD card every 5 sec. or so: `mmc0: cannot verify signal voltage switch`

[image]

## EDIT

It has apparently nothing to do with the SD card: I could install Xubuntu 22.04 on an external drive (SSD), I can boot on it, but everything freezes after 1 or 2 mn. Hypothesis:

- this PC is not fully compatible with Linux (at least the *ubuntu distributions)
- it has a hardware problem (this is an office PC with Windows 10 installed on the internal drive, and I have also experienced some freezes with Windows, although much less frequent (say 3/4 times during one year)

Comment: If it's frozen and you're unable to switch to text terminal (*to explore what is at issue*), OR unable even to command a restart via keyboard (ie. SysRq) then I'd blame the ISO write given your details.  Needing to power down means a kernel panic (*why the SysRq commands can't be used*) which I'd suggest relates to hardware issues OR the ISO was corrupted (*did you verify it as per documented instructions?*) OR (*more likely in my experience*) the ISO failed to write correctly to media (*why you need to check md5sum check completed; using another box if necessary*).

Comment: Maybe useful.... refer https://askubuntu.com/questions/993407/is-verifying-isos-downloaded-from-the-official-website-worthwhile/993409#993409  and my answer on is verifying ISOs worth it... but also look at my other added answer on "*Media Checks*"  (I added it to that question so I had a single URL to provide... but I'm performing that check on any installation issue before anything else...  fast & easy assuming your hardware is good)   Do note:   I don't install to SD cards, but which 22.04 version did you install?  Maybe try the other `calamares` version available on the other 22.04 ISO

Comment: @guiverc I have checked the ISO shasum256 and it's OK. It's not clear to me what you mean by "Media checks". At least with the 20.04 installer I have clearly seen the the squashfs was being verified during the boot. I downloaded [lubuntu-22.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso](https://cdimages.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/22.04/release/lubuntu-22.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso). What is this other ISO you are talking about, I can see only one?

Comment: Lubuntu has released 22.04 (https://lubuntu.me/jammy-released/ where you'll see it has `calamares` 3.2.41.1) and 22.04.1 (https://lubuntu.me/jammy-1-released/ with `calamares` 3.2.60)  ... which had quite a few differences as I recall.  You can search for *squashfs* errors in system logs, with 22.04 the media check runs in the background, so I look for the scan completing & reporting no issues with *modern* media like 22.04)   FYI:  Ubuntu sites always try & offer the *latest* so 22.04.1 will be *much!* easier to find.

Comment: @guiverc Maybe I was not clear: I did try with both the 22.04.1 and 20.04.5 versions, so different versions of calamares as well, and both end up with the same problem, so I doubt the problem comes from calamares itself. I did download the ISO file from the official Ubuntu site (then created the bootable USB key with Unetbootin on macOS, I did that several times in the past without any problem). I'll try checking the `squashfs` file this evening.

Comment: Just FYI:   There are cases where `ubiquity` (used by Xubuntu) can succeed where `calamares` (used by Lubuntu) will not; there are other issues in `ubiquity` that don't exist in `calamares` (all software has strengths + weaknesses), but both Xubuntu, Lubuntu and all Ubuntu systems of the same release use the same software with minor exception (such as installed, desktop & some apps) as all are built using same repositories on same infrastructure (just different seeds to select packages used).   If it's kernel related; try a different stack as you mention only trying 5.15 kernel stack

Comment: @guiverc As mentionned in the OP, I have tried both Lubuntu/Calamares and Xubuntu/Ubiquity, 22.04 or 20.04 (hence different kernels version), and I have even tried installing Manjaroo: in all cases it ends up with freezes. So my conclusion at the moment is that the PC is faulty.

Comment: Found [this](https://medium.com/@natchanan.th/linux-5-x-random-kernel-panic-workaround-4e063e4d34a7) and [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/k4imsd/freeze_on_kernels_419_because_of_i915_dell/). Apparently kernels > 4.19 end up freezing on this Dell. I am trying now Xubuntu 18.04 (kernel 4.15)

Comment: So far so good with 18.04.1... I have been using it for 30mn now, without any freeze. Just, before updating I have to apply the suggested fix for more recent kernels.

Comment: FYI:  If you used Xubuntu 18.04 or 18.04.1 media to do the install; the kernel stack you're using is called the GA kernel stack, it'll remain at 4.15 for the life of 18.04.  Only media 18.04.2 & later defaults to the HWE (hardware enablement kernel) which upgrades during the life...

Comment: OK, so you mean that at least I can apply all 18.04 updates and the kernel will stay on 4.15 ?

Comment: Yep if you used media that defaulted to the GA kernels tack (for Xubuntu that was 18.04 & 18.04.1 ISO/media.  With Ubuntu *flavors* like Xubuntu installs with 18.04.2 & later upgrade: 18.04 used the 4.18 kernel on install, 18.04.3 used 5.0 kernel on install, 18.04.4 used 5.3 kernel on install, & 18.04.5 (5.4 on install) but all of 18.04.2 up upgrade to the 5.4 kernel which is the last of the HWE kernels for *bionic* (18.04).  Installs with 18.04 & 18.04.1 media use the GA stack that doesn't change (also default for server installs as it's the most stable option).

Answer (score 1):

## Diagnostic

It turns out that the kernels >4.19 are the culprits. The problem is related to the iGPU (Intel core i5-8250U with UHD 620 on the Latitude 7490) and the "Panel Self Refresh" feature that is enabled by default on kernels >4.19.

https://medium.com/@natchanan.th/linux-5-x-random-kernel-panic-workaround-4e063e4d34a7

https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/k4imsd/freeze_on_kernels_419_because_of_i915_dell/

It seems that some other Dell models are concerned, but it's not clear if all of them have a UHD 620 iGPU, or if models of other brands are concerned too...

## Solutions

I installed Xubuntu 18.04 LTS (kernel 4.15) and had no more freeze.

The solution with more recent kernels is to disable the PSR feature, by creating this configuration file:

`sudo echo "options i915 enable_psr=0" > /etc/modprobe.d/i915.conf`

In practice I created the file under Xubuntu 18.04, and then I upgraded to 20.04, and eventually 22.04. If one wants to directly install a recent version, it seems that the option has to be passed to Grub at boot time at least to have a session that doesn't freeze (and then one can create the configuration file)

## More troubleshooting

The above solution does actually not completely eliminate the freezes. They can still happen when the screen wakes up after being put to sleep.

To avoid that, I have found that in Settings > Power Manager > Display, it was enough to set "Blank after" on "Never". Strangely, it is possible to use "Put to sleep after" and/or "Switch off after", without having freezes. Also, putting the OS to sleep (suspend) doesn't result in a freeze after wake-up.