# Solving "Kernel Panic - Not Syncing: Attempted to Kill Init!" Error During Ubuntu Installation on Old PC

Tags: lubuntu, 22.04, login-screen

I am currently using Windows 7 on my PC and I am trying to install Ubuntu using a USB drive that I flashed with Balena Etcher. However, when I insert the USB into the port on my old PC and try to install Ubuntu, I encounter a "kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!" error and the installation process is paused.

I have tried the same USB drive on other PCs and it works fine, but I am unable to install Ubuntu on my desired PC. Can anyone help me solve this issue?

Thank you.

Other Information

- Lubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish) 64 bit  (AMD64)
- old pc with 2GB of ram Intel® Core™2 Duo Processor E7200, 1 TB Hard disk
- HP compact dc5800 desktop
- USB 3.0 32GB Samsung (copy not original)

Note: I have tried installing various operating systems such as Ubuntu 22.04, Linux Mint 21.1 Xfce, Zorin OS 15.2 Lite, and Lubuntu, but I encountered errors with all of them. Only Windows was successfully installed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)

Comment: As I am not a professional or tech-savvy user, guidance on how to perform certain tasks would greatly assist me

Comment: Checksum result is ok, I think I have some problems in BIOS setting or hardware

Comment: Thanks; it looks like it's **not** related to ISO... I'll re-add the links from prior comments https://manual.lubuntu.me/lts/1/1.1/retrieving_the_image.html. I also suggested booting & performing checks on other box(es) as per https://askubuntu.com/questions/993407/is-verifying-isos-downloaded-from-the-official-website-worthwhile/993409#993409 (looking at my answers; esp. media check one) .. but I'll look for my Lubuntu *jammy* thumb-drive, boot it & look for the message I look for & provide another comment/suggestion when I find it...

Comment: I have verified the Lubuntu ISO file according to the instructions provided in the manual link you gave me, using the sha256sum command in the Ubuntu terminal. The results I obtained matched those specified in the manual and did not reveal any discrepancies

Comment: FYI:  I'd expect your 22.04.1 ISO to match this http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/22.04.1/release/SHA256SUMS ; the manual still shows the ISO checksum for 22.04 (not 22.04.1 you have).   Boot your thumb-drive on another box; let it idle a few minutes, then open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) & type `journalctl |grep "Check finished"`  where you want to see the line also report "Check finished: no errors found".  If it was me & you have two other boxes; I'd do it on both; if both are "no errors found" it's specific to your current hp5800 box...

Comment: yes, my 22.04.1 ISO is match with this cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/22.04.1/release/SHA256SUMS. No, any errors in it. ISO file is ok no any problem as I already told you, I think the errors in my bios setting or hardware related.

Comment: Did you boot your ISO on another & confirm the media validation check completed as per my prior comment?  I write hundreds of ISOs to media in a year, and find 5-8% of ISO writes fail because it's cheap made made to cost (that's with Sandisk; other brands have a worse failure rate). The next likely could be how you write the ISO (you should CLONE if possible) as I'm not familiar with *Balena Etcher*; but am aware you can write ISOs so they'll boot on specific types of hardware but not others (CLONE avoids this); you didn't specify what other hardware & types you were using.

Comment: I was able to successfully boot the ISO on a Lenovo ThinkPad T430 without encountering any issues. However, when I tried to install it on my HP DC5800, I encountered a kernel boot error. This seems to be a problem specific to my older PC, and I am currently unsure as to what is causing the issue. i am using usb samsung 3.0 32 GB (copy its cheap)

Comment: Unless the hardware is identical; booting the ISO on another box is not a complete test (*the different hardware can cause different parts of the thumb-drive to be used!*), which is why the command I gave you is used (scanning logs for the *Check Finished.. no errors*).  You've so far verified the thumb-drive will boot on another Thinkpad T430, so use one of them (*or test it on another HP 5800 if you don't want to check for the media verification message*).  The ISO write can also be involved (does the T430 boot the same as your HP?, ie. BIOS vs uEFI vs Secure-uEFI etc) thus use CLONE writes.

Comment: I'm not familiar with your box (have hp dc7700, 7900, 8200, & others but no 5800) so I've concentrated on tests I'd perform to rule out factors I'm aware of... So far the most likely cause I see is MEDIA write which you've not ruled out with testing (booting it on other boxes with identical or almost-identical hardware is useful; but I had 5x dell optiplex 755's that were actually 3 different machines due to different hardware used by dell during the machine's life).  If you believe it's *firmware* (ie. BIOS setting) you'll need to check that; as *firmware* is unique to boxes

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. As I mentioned before, I am not a technical expert and I am not very familiar with these kinds of things. However, I tried some commands and found a solution. I will be selling my old machine as it is too outdated and hangs frequently ( 15 to 20 years old). I was simply curious to see how the Ubuntu operating system would perform on this old machine, but unfortunately, I was unlucky. I have decided to purchase a new machine from the market and install Ubuntu on it. Again, I apologize for my lack of understanding of the commands and I appreciate your help

Comment: The *hangs* frequently would make me want to open the box up & perform a *cap-check*, ie. visually check how clean the box was (*vacuum up any dust/fluff etc*) and visually confirm there are no swollen capacitors (*the top of the 'caps' should be smooth & perfectly flat; no swelling*). If the *freezes* are actually locks (ie. it won't resume & you need to restart to get it going), swollen caps on motherboard is what I'd look for, then RAM test; as Windows & Linux allocate RAM from opposite ends they'll *crash/lock* at different times, then PSU (*even good components foul-up with poor power*)..

Comment: Did you ever find get an answer to this issue? Having the exact same problem while trying to install Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 on an older Dell laptop.

Answer (score 1):

Update Firmware and problem solved