# How to create a USB Persistent with Kubuntu distro

Tags: usb, kubuntu, persistence

I have created ubuntu persistent usb drive with mkusb without problems. But when I try to create a persistent usb drive with Kubuntu I have never got it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have more informations to give us ? do you have an error message, what did you tried ?

Comment: Please be specific, what release? in fact what ISO?  Did you verify the ISO as being correct? (ie. https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 etc)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is verifying ISOs downloaded from the official website worthwhile?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993407/is-verifying-isos-downloaded-from-the-official-website-worthwhile)