# Can the installation be stoped and started over again if it freezes

Tags: usb-installation

I was installing the new vision of Ubuntu on Intel Celeron, and about 90% complete it froze, how can I stop the installation and start over

Comment: You've not said what Ubuntu product, what release of that product, nor what ISO you are using (*for some product/releases there are many ISO choices, with each using a different installation*).  On most, I'd switch to text terminal & explore what it's actually doing; as `ubiquity` and `calamares` (esp. older versions of `calamares`) are pretty easy to detect; even if you're using an Ubuntu system using `ubuntu-desktop-installer` or `subiquity` clues can still be detected. You can stop it from terminal OR just restart the system etc..

Comment: Did you verify your ISO?  verify you write of ISO to your installation media?   If you read my answer on this question, https://askubuntu.com/questions/993407/is-verifying-isos-downloaded-from-the-official-website-worthwhile/993409#993409 you'll note it's what I consider *cheap insurance* as in mere seconds you can quickly detect if you'll run into issues (*excluding those related to your hardware - but we hopefully know if our hardware is fully reliable!*)  Ubuntu Desktop is available with 2 installers, Desktop *flavors* also 2, Ubuntu Server uses a different installer ... you're using which?

Comment: If you didn't *validate* your media; the link I provided has another answer on *Media Checks*; just search the page for "*Media Checks*" and adjust for your *unstated* Ubuntu product & release....  I concentrate on Desktop ISOs as that's what I use ~96% of the time

Answer (score 0):

A common cause of the Ubuntu installer freezing partway through is defective sectors on the hard disk. Swapping the hard disk with another hard disk will fix this problem. If you want to rerun the Ubuntu installer from the beginning simply remove the Ubuntu live USB, turn of the computer, and restart the computer with the Ubuntu live USB inserted in a USB port.