# Which option do I choose in the BIOS (MacBook Pro 2009)?

Tags: system-installation, 22.04, live-usb, bios, macbook-pro

It's my first time installing Ubuntu, and I want to install it on a 2009 MacBook Pro. I used my Ubuntu 22.04 live USB thumb drive and got into the BIOS (or what I thought was the BIOS) and I chose the correct drive, but there are 5 options that I can choose from.

- Try or Install Ubuntu
- Ubuntu (safe graphics)
- OEM install (for manufacturers)
- Boot from next volume
- UEFI Firmware Settings

I tried the first two options, but it said

> error: file '/casper/vmlinuz' not found

Which one do I choose or what do I do?

Comment: You mention your release (22.04) but not which product (Server? Desktop? etc) thus what installer you're using is *unknown*.. but did you verify your ISO after download?  (eg. https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0) and write of ISO to media?  as if either ISO was invalid/flawed, or write wasn't perfect, you'll get a message such as you describe...  From your message, I'd re-validate your ISO and if that is good, re-write ISO to media; and if you need help, you should specify how you wrote it, as your error implies to me invalid ISO or write of ISO to media.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is verifying ISOs downloaded from the official website worthwhile?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993407/is-verifying-isos-downloaded-from-the-official-website-worthwhile)