# How to fix boot Ubuntu - SQUASHFS error: Unable to read inode 0x503

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows, asus, bios

I have Windows 10 installed on an Asus and I want to switch to Ubuntu 22.04, so I tried to install Ubuntu. When I started the installation, I saw this error message. I tried everything, but at first nothing worked.

[image: U]

Comment: Your installation media is faulty (*the SQUASHFS errors are errors reading your media*).  Did you verify your ISO after download?  I'd use another machine to verify your write (*if you don't have capacity of verifying write of ISO on your writing machine*).  You didn't specify which Ubuntu 22.04 LTS product (the installer is selected by the ISO you download; and you didn't specify, only mentioning the release itself; ie. 22.04).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is verifying ISOs downloaded from the official website worthwhile?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993407/is-verifying-isos-downloaded-from-the-official-website-worthwhile)

Comment: A lot of details you didn't provide really matter; as 22.04 is newer than 20.04; the method of writing can matter (esp. if you're not using software that reformats the ISO via options & wasn't written to cope with the 22.04 release!).  As you didn't specify what product, your kernel stack maybe a GA (5.15) or HWE (6.2) which can impact (due to age) what hardware it can cope with (*you gave few clues as to your Asus hardware*). Did you download & use an appropriate ISO for your hardware? an older or newer kernel stack on your 22.04 ISO? as you didn't mention which 22.04.

Comment: FYI:   Bad downloads are extremely rare in my experience; the write of the ISO to thumb-drive is the most common cause; either through error (by selecting inappropriate options for your hardware; a simple CLONE of ISO to media is most reliable as it'll work on legacy BIOS, uEFI & Secure-uEFI where as reformatted may not!) with updated ISO writing software, (there are many ISO types; not all software writes all types; stick to documented procedures for Ubuntu ISOs I'd recommend).  If you're hardware is new, you may need newer software.

Comment: The "SGX disabled by BIOS" message is just for information. It's not an error.

Comment: Changed the title to reflect the actual issue